# Firebase Database values in Analytics

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I'm very new to Google Firebase. I've gone through a few tutorials and I think its a great platform.

My question is - can I somehow set up a dashboard within Firebase Analytics itself - to pull data from the RealTime database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to import Firebase Database data into Firebase Analytics.

Comment: Well, That's sad :(